# A SF novel with a woman who likes to sit on the floor

Tags: story-identification, space

I read this SF novel at least 20 years ago and probably it is even much older.
I remember almost nothing. I vaguely **believe** that I remember it is one novel in a series, but I am not sure.
It is something like a space opera, with people living on different planets. One planet has at least part of the population originating from China or Japan. One woman of such origin at some points wonders how people (on her planet or on other ones) originating from our "western" part of Earth can feel comfortable while unnaturally "breaking their body at right angles" when it is so natural to wind her body around herself in contact with the ground.

Now if I remember only this small element of this novel, it may be because I did not much like it. I **believe** that I had enjoyed other books of that series and only kept reading this one for that reason.

But mostly it is because I feel she and I are not made of the same basic components. I feel very well seating on a chair, my back upright, by thighs horizontal and my legs vertical. On the ground my only comfortable position is lying down. If I have to keep my back upright there is absolutely no position I can keep more than a few minutes. I switch my legs from right to left, in front of me, whatever, I kneel, or bring my knees under my chin, changing position every few minutes. I took a yoga class once. The sentence "Sit on the floor and relax" is for me an oxymoron. I never spent a more stressing time.

So I remember this Chinese (or Japanese ?) woman just because she felt comfortable on the floor rather than on a good chair leaving vertical room for the legs...

---

Maybe I should add that, IIRC, there were no **discussion** about how to sit. It was just a private thought of this character. Also IIRC, she was a very lonely character, spending most of her time sitting alone in her room.

Comment: Maybe a long shot, since I don't remember any seating discussion, but it could be John Meaney's novel *To Hold Infinity* (1998). https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11121476

Comment: There was a woman character in Poul Anderson's "Tau Zero" who made similar complaints about sitting in chairs vs sitting on the floor.

Comment: @user888379 I found a synopsis of "Tau Zero" but it did not ring any bell in connection with my story. It does remind me of "Pushing Ice" which I asked about some time ago but I'm pretty sure it is not related to my story here.

Comment: My brain went to Orson Scott Card's *Xenocide*, but I don't think there is such a scene.

Comment: Xenocide **is** in the Ender series ! And I remember I did not like is as much as Ender's Game and Speaker for the Dead. I don't remember it much, but I just checked on Wiki, and there is this character Han Qing-jao... I do believe it is her ! I'll try and find out. Do give it as an answer so I can accept it if I am convinced. It is not much of a"scene", just a passing thought. But I remember it because it is exactly the **contrary** of the way I am. Most readers would probably not notice such a minor detail if they can attend a yoga class without feeling horribly stressed !

Comment: @FuzzyBoots you got it right: the "passing thought" is probably the one in the next book, *Children of the Mind*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@FuzzyBoots has the right of it. The "space opera with planets populated by people of different Terran countries" is a ringer for Ender's diaspora, which would make the "chinese planet" the planet of Path.

So I cheated and did a keyword search for *angle* on my ePub of *Children of the Mind*, book IV of the *Ender* series, where there is a servant girl, Si Wang-Mu, that I thought would be suitable since she's a key character and we get to "listen" to much of her thoughts - and indeed,

> Wang-mu, familiar only with the taste of one world, and really only of
> one man in that one world, could hardly evaluate Jane's choices. There
> were places to sit--both Western chairs, which **folded people into
> alternating right angles** and never seemed comfortable to Wang-mu, and
> Eastern mats, which encouraged people to **twine themselves into circles
> of harmony with the Earth**.

I got the planet wrong though. Even if Si Wang-Mu is from the Chinese-originating planet of Path, the scene takes place on the more Western-oriented, Japanese-colonized world of Divine Wind.

Comment: So it was not Han Qing-jao after all. But your quote is exactly the one I remembered. And it was not so much Xenocide that I did not like, because I did read the next one, but Children of the Mind which was the last one I read. "twine myself into circles" on a mat... me : shudders...